# Network Policy always blocks Metadata Server on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am using GKE and I want to write some network policies, but as soon as I add the following Policy I get this error:

```
url.Error Get "http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes
```

When I delete the policy everything works.

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ template "name" . }}
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "name" . }}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 3307
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 3306
      protocol: TCP
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 169.254.169.254/32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: {{ template "name" . }}
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "name" . }}
  policyTypes:
    - Egress
  egress:
    - ports:
      - port: 53
        protocol: UDP
      - port: 53
        protocol: TCP
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
      - port: 3307
        protocol: TCP
    - to:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: 169.254.169.252/32
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 988
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use network policy with GKE [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity), you must allow egress to the following IP addresses and port numbers so your Pods can communicate with the [GKE metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy#limitations_and_requirements). For clusters running GKE version 1.21.0-gke.1000 and later, allow egress to 169.254.169.252/32 on port 988. For clusters running GKE versions before 1.21.0-gke.1000, allow egress to 127.0.0.1/32 on port 988. To avoid disruptions during auto-upgrades, allow egress to all of these IP addresses and ports.

So, As per your YAML file, you need to pass the port 988 also to allow egress because  cidr: 169.254.169.254/32 as this pass only on 988 port. So that there will not be any error on metadata.

[An example NetworkPolicy might look like this:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource)

Comment: The metadata server listens on port 80.

Comment: One thing I still don't get is why its working now, before it was allowing access to 169.254.169.254/32 on every port.

Comment: As default it is working on 988 port so,  need to mention the port specifically in order to allow access.